Adding versioning in star schema design
I am in a situation where i have to add version in existing dimension tables . For eg.
I have 7 dimensions tables and a fact table (with total existing data of 500GB)
Now the requirement is dimensions can have multiple versions and combinations and need to redesign and update existing structure . What is the best possible way to implement

Add version column in dimension tables  or use snowflake model to have versions separately
Sample structure





Product Table (Dim)
Benefit table (Dim)
Component table (Dim)




Product_id (surrogate key)PK
Benefit_id (surrogate key)PK
Comp_id(surrogate key)PK


Attr2
Attr2
Attr2






fact




Product_id


Benefit_id


Comp_id


val1


val2



Now the requirement is dimensions can have multiple versions and combinations and need to redesign and update existing structure . What is the best possible way to implement
Add version column in dimension tables  or use snowflake model to have versions separately

Hi - it’s not clear, to me, what you are talking about. Do you mean versioning the structure of your database or versioning the data held in your database. It would help if you updated your question with examples e.g. what would a version 1 look like and then what would a version 2 look like

With current design id is the PK ,for e.g Product_id is the PK and with versioning requirement ,  can have multiple versions for the same id and product_id +version_id will be the new PK . Versioning to be implemented in all DIM tables and all DIM table PK will change to id+version_id .I hope i made it clear

It sounds like you're talking about a Slowly Changing Dimension (SCD). If so, this is a very standard data modelling pattern and there are loads of resources describing this - can I suggest that you have a look at SCDs and see if this is what you want? If it isn't can you explain why it's not what you are looking for? If it is, and you still have a question then please update your question with whatever you want to ask. Thanks
